# How widespread are "advaita vedanta" followers among modern Hindus?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, purva-mimamsa

How widespread are secular beliefs based on advaita vedanta among the modern Sanatan dharma population? I was under the impression this was a major movement, but I seem to hear hints otherwise.

Comment: Unless you explain your **impressions**  and **hints that you heard**, you may not get proper answer@Kauva Aatma

Comment: My entirely anecdotal opinion is that the vast majority of practicing Hindus are blissfully ignorant of Advaita Vedanta, let alone follow it.

Comment: your question makes no sense. Advaita Vedantists are followers of the Uttara Mimamsa, not the Purva.

Comment: thank you so much for that answer @iruvar. that was exactly the information I sought!! namaste